# Alternatives for WordUtils.capitalize?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to capitalize every word in a string using `WordUtils.capitalize(String)` because it does exactly what I wanted. However it is now deprecated.

What method should I use instead? Or do I have to write my own method?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The implementation in `commons-lang3` is deprecated. However, the same method is implemented in `commons-text`. Therefore, you may use essentially the same method, but will need to add a new .jar file and adjust the import statement.

From the [javadoc of `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html):

> as of 3.6, use commons-text WordUtils instead

If using Maven (or similar), add the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

[The reference for Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/): Apache Commons Text is a library focused on algorithms working on strings.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was importing import org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils; and that was the problem. Such a strange thing do: import the commons-text, but don't use that import, but use the import from commons.lang3.text.*

Comment: works like charm, especially in the latest spring boot versions

Answer (score 12):

You can use **apache.commons**'s [**StringUtils.capitalise()**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-):

> **public static String capitalize(String str)**
>
> Capitalizes a String changing the first character to title case as per
>   Character.toTitleCase(int). No other characters are changed.

Instead of `WordUtils` class use `StringUtils` from the same package, so you don't have to change your project configuration by adding extra jars.

**Alternative:**

Or you can implement it yourself, you can try something like this:

```
String str = "john";
String newStr = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
```

Will print `John`.

Comment: Good point on the `StringUtils.capitalize(String)` -- it would avoid having to add another .jar file.

Comment: @KevinO yes indeed it's just another class of the package.

Comment: WordUtils.capitalize capitalizes the first word and the remaining characters are converted to lower case while StringUtils.capitalize only converts the first to capital and doesn't change the remaining to lower

Comment: @Aditya And yes this is the requested behaviour here, Just the first chnarcter should be changed :)

Comment: No, the request was to "capitalize EVERY word in a string".  Example: "deck builder" should be changed to "Deck Builder".  With StringUtils.capitalize you get "Deck builder". With WordUtils.capitalize you get "Deck Builder" as expected but this is deprecated. So user was looking for an alternative to WordUtils.capitalize and StringUtils.capitalize provides a different result. In other words, this is not the right answer.