# MongoDB Java: how to get write error document?

Tags: java, mongodb, bulkinsert, mongodb-java

I'm inserting 1000 documents in mongodb 3.6 at once using an unordered bulk via mongodb java api 3.6.1 and the method `insertMany(List<Document>)`.

```
try {
    collection.insertMany(docs);
} catch (MongoBulkWriteException e) {
    // e is :
   // Bulk write operation error on server myserver.com:27011. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: foodb.bar index: bar.id_1 dup key: { : 1 }', details={ }}].     
}
```

Let's say only one document triggered a duplicate key error. All others 999 documents were successfully inserted.
**How can I know which document triggered the error ?**

Of course when getting the duplicate key error, I could search my list of documents with the `bar.id` that was duplicated but it's inconvenient (it means parsing the WriteError message...) and if there is two documents with the same `bar.id` in the `List<Document>`, it's almost impossible to know which triggered the error without asking the db.

Thanks

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094415/retrieving-the-specific-mongodb-key-from-duplicatekeyexception-that-was-actually

Comment: Could be, but my question is more general, as any other write error can occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MongoBulkWriteException` contains a `List<BulkWriteError>`, each failed write will be represented by an element in this list. Each element in this list contains an `index` attribute which is populated with the index of the element in the supplied list of documents.

So, you can use this `index` to work out which of the supplied documents failed.

Here's a test case showing this in action:

```
@Test
public void canBulkWriteAndIdentifySpecificFailedDocuments() throws IOException {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClientFactory().create();

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("stackoverflow").getCollection("bulkwrite");

    // fresh start for this test case
    collection.drop();

    Document knownDocument = new Document().append("name", new BsonString("beep"));
    collection.insertOne(knownDocument);

    collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("name", 1), new IndexOptions().unique(true));

    int createDuplicateOnIndex = 2;
    List<Document> docs = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == createDuplicateOnIndex) {
            // deliberately trigger a duplicate key exception
            docs.add(knownDocument);
        } else {
            docs.add(new Document().append("name", new BsonString("beep" + i)));
        }
    }

    try {
        collection.insertMany(docs, new InsertManyOptions().ordered(false));
    } catch (MongoBulkWriteException ex) {
        assertThat(ex.getWriteResult().getInsertedCount(), is(4));
        assertThat(ex.getMessage(), containsString("duplicate key error"));
        assertThat(ex.getWriteErrors().size(), is(1));
        assertThat(ex.getWriteErrors().get(0).getIndex(), is(createDuplicateOnIndex));
        assertThat(ex.getWriteErrors().get(0).getCode(), is(11000));
        assertThat(ex.getWriteErrors().get(0).getMessage(), startsWith("E11000 duplicate key error"));
    }
}
```

In this test case we ...

1. Write a document
2. Create a unique index on the target collection
3. Write a collection of documents (using `new InsertManyOptions().ordered(false)` for an unordered write), one of which breaches the unique index
4. Assert that the bulk insert causes a `MongoBulkWriteException` to be thrown and that this exception reports 4 successful writes and 1 failed write with `E11000 duplicate key error` and an index value which clearly shows that this failure is associated with the third document (`index == 2`) in the given list.